# Non-generated classname selector in css module

Tags: css, css-modules, react-css-modules

Let's say we have a third-party `CardComponent` like this

```js
<Card title="This is a title in the header">This is text in the body</Card>
```

And this renders in plain HTML

```html
<div class="Card">
  <div class="CardHeader"></div>
  <div class="CardBody"></div>
</div>
```

And I'm using css modules for styling (scss in this case).

```css
.customCard {
  .CardBody {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

And then add the class to Card

```js
import styles from ...
...
<Card className={styles.customCard} ...>...</Card>
```

Above will not work because it creates a generated class for `CardBody` like `CardBody_sjkdh43`. Is there a way to select non generated classnames in modules? Or is this only possible in the old fashion way to use a stylesheet?

[Demo SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-css-modules-5z4fz)

Comment: It seems you can only access customCard class which we pass as props nothing else :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is to use the `:global()` selector in CSS modules.

For more info: [Exceptions - CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#exceptions)

Example the code:

```
<div class={styles.myClass}>
    <SomeComponentWithOwnCss />
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div class="myClass_s4jkdh3">
    <div class="SomeComponentWithOwnCss"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.myClass div:global(.SomeComponentWithOwnCss) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Working example here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-modules-global-selector-i5khz)

Comment: Nice. Simple and clear. Pretty straight forward. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this for a more convenient approach with SCSS:

```scss
.parent :global {
  .non-cssmodule-class {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```
<div className={styles.parent}>
  <div className="non-cssmodule-class" />
</div>
```

output:

```html
<style>
  .filename-parent__7MR41 .non-cssmodule-class { color: red; }
</style>
<div class="filename-parent__7MR41">
    <div class="non-cssmodule-class"></div>
</div>
```